# Payara automactic deployment ejb error but not manually

Tags: java, docker, ejb, war, payara

As of Payara version 5.2021.7 I can deploy my application automatically in docker on container start but it errors with `Invalid ejb jar [my application]: it contains zero ejb.`

However, I can log into the UI and deploy the application manually without any errors.

I'm pretty new to the java/payara world. Does anyone know why deploying it automatically requires an `.ejb` file but doing it manually doesn't?

Comment: It looks like the command the auto deploy is running is `deploy /opt/payara/deployments/authn.simple`. authn.simple being my application. If i change the postboot script to include the war file, so `deploy /opt/payara/deployments/authn.simple/authn.simple-2.0.0.war` it deploys successfully. It looks like the autodeploy isn't including the war file in its path

Comment: ah ok so inside my deployments' dir was a folder called "authn.simple" and within that lay the war file. Removing the folder and having the war file in the top level deployments dir fixed the issue.

My understanding was that the deployment process searched for war files in the sub directories and appended them to the postboot commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to have the war file in the top level deployment directory (`$DEPLOY_DIR`) instead of having it nested inside another folder.